# Googling "London DevDays" leads to outdated site

Tags: bug, status-completed, devdays, devdays-2011

For me (in Germany), the first hit when Googling

```
London DevDays
```

leads to http://stackoverflow.carsonified.com/events/london/

which is talking about **October 28** without mentioning a year (probably from 2009), while the actual 2011 DevDays are taking place in November.

Also, the London venue is marked as "Sold out" on that site, like many others, while for the 2011 DevDays, that doesn't seem to be the case yet.

Those pages need to be taken down. Although I dig their design! They look *really* cool. I'd like to see that design back for the 2012 DevDays!

Comment: Getting the same result here (Norway), although the correct link is the second hit and _it_ does say 2011 in the title. It would probably be a good idea to do something about the old site, though.

Comment: This appears to have become true again, sadly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On my request, Carsonified redirected their old site to our new one about a month ago - July 25 to be exact.  I'm not sure why the event/city pages didn't get redirected, but I will follow up with them.